# How can I install kerberised services on debian?

Tags: linux, debian, telnet, kerberos

I installed kerberos in my debian environment and made it work with SSH. I also would like to try it with other services but I could not install them on debian. I followed several tutorials e.g.

- https://www.debian-administration.org/article/570/MIT_Kerberos_installation_on_Debian (paragraph Installing Kerberized Services)
- https://itservices.stanford.edu/service/kerberos/install_debian

When I tried to run commands

```
apt-get install krb5-rsh-server
```

OR

```
apt-get install krb5-telnetd
```

I encountered on this error:

```
user@pc# apt-get install krb5-rsh-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package krb5-rsh-server
```

I am running this version of Linux (Debian): Debian 3.16.3-2 (2014-09-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Do I need to install some other package to be able to install kerberized services?

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Also, that's the Linux version, yes, but that's only the _kernel_ version – it has nothing to do with the _Debian_ version (which is probably 8.0-Jessie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These services are no longer packaged in Debian Jessie, nor maintained by MIT Kerberos developers, nor in any way recommended to be used. Heimdal has recently removed their versions as well. (The kerberized telnetd, for example, only supported DES.)

(That said, you can still find the MIT services' source code at https://github.com/krb5/krb5-appl.)

I suggest experimenting with modern services which fully support Kerberos via GSSAPI and/or SASL, for example (in no particular order):

- OpenLDAP
- Apache (mod_auth_gssapi or the older mod_auth_kerb); Lighttpd
- Samba (SMB)
- Dovecot (IMAP/POP3), Postfix (SMTP), Cyrus IMAP
- ejabberd, Prosody (XMPP via cyrus sasl backend)
- MariaDB (auth_gssapi), PostgreSQL, MongoDB
- ProFTPd (mod_gss)
- BIND 9 (dynamic DNS updates via GSS-TSIG)
- NFS or OpenAFS if you want something particularly arcane.